# How to get my Facebook friends with OmniAuth in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, rubygems

I have a simple Rails app where I can log in with using Facebook through OmniAuth.

Is there any way to obtain my Facebook friends with using OmniAuth Facebook gem? Do I need to use any other gems for that? (if so, which ones are the best ones - the most updated/etc).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [koala gem](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) which works well Facebook graph api.

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_access_token)
friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
```

Comment: on using @grpah.get_object("me") -> I am getting user name and its id but on using @graph.get_connections("me","friends") I am getting an empty array. Why it is so?

Comment: is there any other solution by getting friends list of facebook in rails application?

Comment: @NimishJain you need to set the permissions when you get your token, look at the fb graph api

Answer (score 1):

Try using gem 'fb_graph' for it. Check the link for it
https://github.com/nov/fb_graph

You can get your fb friends by

```
@fb_friends = FbGraph::User.me(USER-FB-ACCESS-Token).friends
```

Here, `USER-FB-ACCESS-Token` is the access token that one user will will get after connecting to facebook via omniauth facebook.

Comment: I got the token but unable to understand what to do next. No proper steps are shown on github.